# OncePerRequestFilter doesn't include last character from response body

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am trying to implement content digest header in my REST api. When I am creating digest for my response it always omits the last character.

public class ContentDigestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletResponse responseToUse = response;
    if (!isAsyncDispatch(request) && !(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
        responseToUse = new HttpStreamingAwareContentCachingResponseWrapper(response, request);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, responseToUse);

    updateResponse(request, responseToUse);
}

private void updateResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
            WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
    Assert.notNull(responseWrapper, "ContentCachingResponseWrapper not found");
    HttpServletResponse rawResponse = (HttpServletResponse) responseWrapper.getResponse();
    int statusCode = responseWrapper.getStatusCode();

    if (rawResponse.isCommitted()) {
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
    else{
        String digest = getContentDigest(responseWrapper.getContentInputStream());

        rawResponse.setHeader("X-Digest",digest);
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}


protected String getContentDigest(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    try {
        byte[] dataArray = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);

        //dataArray doesn't include last character of response body.
        System.out.println("Response Body: " + new String(dataArray,"UTF-8"));

        String digest = ""; //Generate digest with HMAC-SHA512

        return digest;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "NoDigest";
}

private static class HttpStreamingAwareContentCachingResponseWrapper extends ContentCachingResponseWrapper {

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    public HttpStreamingAwareContentCachingResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(response);
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return super.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return super.getWriter();
    }
}
```

}

In the method getContentDigest if I print dataArray it doesn't include last character of response

Comment: Try calling `response.flushBuffer()`.

Comment: Already tried. It doesn't work.